# Interpretation of function

Tags: analysis

Is there a natural interpretation of the following expression for a differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

$f(x) - xf'(x)$

Thanks for every answer and hint :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is "natural", but $$f(x)-xf'(x)=-x^2\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{f(x)}{x}\right]$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $f(x+h) \approx f(x)+hf'(x)$ and so, by taking $h=-x$, we have  $f(0) \approx f(x) - xf'(x)$.

This approximation is good only for $x$ near $0$.

Comment: mhm... they consider the $\lim$ for $x\rightarrow \infty$ of the expression above...